# How would you use SurfaceView and choreographer concurrently?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am currently working on an Android game in which I am writing the engine myself.  I have been using just a surface view and a thread for updating and rendering the game. The problem is that the motion is not smooth. I have implemented methods such as deltaTime and interpolation but the motion is still not completely smooth. after close analysis I have concluded that the stuttering is caused by non uniform frame updates which I hope to fix with using choreographer as well.

My question is How do I use the two together? How do I let the surfaceholder retrieve and post the canvas under control of the choreographer?

Since they both have Framecallbacks How would that fit together?

(sorry for the bad formatting, I am writing this on mobile)

Comment: all you need is a `Thread` with a `Looper`, you can directly use a `HandlerThread` or create your own custom `Thread` that calls `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` inside its `run` method

Comment: Suggested viewing material as you are writing your own engine (old but still good): https://youtu.be/U4Bk5rmIpic and https://youtu.be/7-62tRHLcHk